# Float not affecting sibling div's paragraphs.

Tags: css, web, css-float

I'm trying to create a web page, that has three columns of text, but these columns float around a central quote. 
It's supposed to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhqrQ.jpg

but it currently looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWHLK.jpg

The problem is, the "float:left" applied to the quote is not affecting the text, because the text is in a containing div. I can't take the text out of the div, because then it won't be in 3 columns. Is there some trick I don't know to fix this?

Here's my code if that helps:

```css
#magicquote{
 position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    width: 50%;
 float: left;
}

#maintext{
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "teststylesheet.css" type = "text/css" media = "all"/>
    </head>
    <body>
  <p id = "magicquote"> lorem</p>
  <div id = "maintext">
   <p> lorem</p>
   <p> lorem</p>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I do not think what I want to do is possible in current (2016) CSS without weird "hacks". I appreciate Steve Hartley's answer, and what he says certainly works for static web pages. However, I'm trying to make a responsive page and Steve's code would leave large white spaces and the window shrunk.

To make this more responsive, I'm going to add an empty div where Steve put his pre element. Then I'll use JS to change this div's height depending on the location and size of the other elements in my page.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add pre tags in between your main text div and the first paragraph.

hit the enter key a few times to create some lines, the pre tags preserve white space in the html. You can create as much whitespace between the pre tags as you desire.

You may want to narrow up your quote paragraph so it doesn't overlap into the second column.

This is what it looks like for me after changing your magic quote width to 40% https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAADW.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "teststylesheet.css" type = "text/css" media = "all"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id = "magicquote"> lorem</p>
        <div id = "maintext">
            <pre>




            </pre>
            <p> lorem</p>
            <p> lorem</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```